# Why this email input field with a required attribute fail W3C validation? (html5 page)

Tags: html, forms, email, input, w3c-validation

Trying to fix 2 errors when validating a contact page that I am working on. It does have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the page as inputs with required need to be.

Here is the W3C [Link](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmitunetwork.com%2Fcontact&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&ss=1) to the results.

Code in question:

```
<input class="input-box form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" value="" data-error="Please add a valid email address." required>
```

w3c errors:

> Attribute placeholder is only allowed when the input type is e-mail,
>   number, password, search, tel, text, or url.

and

> Attribute required is only allowed when the input type is checkbox,
>   date, datetime, datetime-local, e-mail, file, month, number, password,
>   radio, search, tel, text, time, url, or week.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: You should insert the relevant code to your question instead of a link. Add the least amount of code that still makes sense and still produces the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C validator had a bug (only for a few days), which [got fixed](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2015Mar/0015.html) in the meantime.

Your snippet does validate now.

Comment: Thank you!! It was driving me crazy.